# how can i use luis action binding to trigger an intent after prompting the user for mentioning missing entities

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

This post is in context to bot framework in C#(.Net)

so i wanted to know that if my expected utterance from the user is:

"show me the projects starting on 3rd march"

but the user misses the date entity and writes

"show me the projects starting on"

now i want to prompt the user for the date(which is the missing entity) that please mention the date.

and then simply run the intent now.

Which is the best approach to take it forward ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Nicolas R’s reply, he has shared idea and approach to achieve your requirement, you can refer to it.

Besides, you can refer to the following sample code to prompt for providing the date when the specific intent is reached and required entity is missing.

```
[Serializable]
public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{

    string bdate;
    public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        "{ID_here}",
        "{subscriptionKey_here}", 
        domain: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")))
    {
    }

    //....
    //for other intents

    [LuisIntent("GetProjectInfo")]
    public async Task GetProjectInfoIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result) 
    {

        if (result.Entities.Count == 0)
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(
            context: context,
            resume: ResumeGetDate,
            prompt: "Please enter the date",
            retry: "Please try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
        }


    }

    public async Task ResumeGetDate(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> mes)
    {
        bdate = await mes;

        await context.PostAsync($"You reached GetProjectInfo intent. And you entered the date: {bdate}");

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result) 
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. You said: {result.Query}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: can i connect with you over email ?

Comment: Hi @ShivainMattoo, glad to hear that the reply with sample help you solve the problem. If you have another bot related issues, feel free to post in forum, I think I and other community members will give help, which would be better than discussing via email.

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the best approach to take it forward ?

- Create a method that handles the intent (method1) and another for the business case that should be done after (method2)
- In method1, check for your possible missing data. If none, call method2, else call a method (method3) to get the missing values, and in the resume of this method3 call method2 when you have your values

Comment: Hey! ya this i am aware of i was just avoiding the use of using method2 twice. and tryinng to use luis action binding, but it seems super complicated. ill stick with this i guess